# Mysql error while creating FK

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, schema, foreign-key

here is structure of both tables

```
category table
CREATE TABLE category (
`catID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`catID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and the second table `projects`

```
CREATE TABLE `projects` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`catID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`industryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `dsID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`countryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `catID` (`catID`),
KEY `industryID` (`industryID`),
KEY `dsID` (`dsID`),
KEY `countryID` (`countryID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now to add FK to tables here is the query but i keep getting the error

```
Can't create table .... (errno: 150)
ALTER TABLE `projects`  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_catID FOREIGN KEY projects (catID)  REFERENCES category (catID)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a foreign key between two tables the data type of the columns that are taking part in the relationship must have the same data type. In the example you have posted above it is failing because the `Categories` table defines `CatID` as a `BIGINT` wheras in the `Projects` table you have defined it as a `INT`. Changing the data type of `CatID` in the `Projects` table to `BIGINT` should resolve your problem.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: perfect dude it resolves my problem beacuse as you have mentioned the datatypes are different of both coloumns thanks for pointing me

Comment: No problem - glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

The data type/size/signedness have to be identical on a foreign key constraint.

```
`category`.`catID` bigint(20)
`projects`.`catID` int(11)
```

Use bigint for both or int for both.

Also, this statement is probably not going to do exactly what you intended, even when it works:

```
ALTER TABLE `projects` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_catID FOREIGN KEY projects (catID) REFERENCES category (catID)
-- this position is an optional index name, not a table name ^^^^^
```

You probably intend to do this, instead:

```
ALTER TABLE `projects` ADD CONSTRAINT FK_catID FOREIGN KEY (catID) REFERENCES category (catID)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name
ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]]
FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
[ON DELETE RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION]
[ON UPDATE RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION]
```

Answer (score -1):

Please find the solution here.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE category (
    -> `catID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> `title` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    -> `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ->  PRIMARY KEY (`catID`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `projects` (
    -> `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> `catID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    -> `industryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->  `dsID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    -> `countryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    -> `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    -> KEY `catID` (`catID`),
    -> KEY `industryID` (`industryID`),
    -> KEY `dsID` (`dsID`),
    -> KEY `countryID` (`countryID`)
    ->  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE `projects`
        ADD CONSTRAINT FK_catID FOREIGN KEY projects (catID)
            REFERENCES category (catID) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: What does this answer provide that hasn't been already provided by the two previous answers?

Comment: i have alredy accepted the answer and your provided answer is worng so please remove that answer before downvoting